# Undefined local variable or method when use before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-2

I am upgrading a project from rails 2.0.2 to 3.2.13. I was using `before_filter` :`build_menu` like this

```
class MyController < ApplicationController   
  layout 'main'

  before_filter :build_menu 
  ... 
protected   
  def build_menu
    @menu = []   
  end 
end
```

now with Rails 3 am getting the error:

> undefined local variable or method `build_menu`

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with that piece of code, are you sure the build_menu isn't being called anywhere else? (maybe a class that can't access that protected method)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.
Turned out I had mismatched `def`-`end` in the file, but for some reasons the IDE was not giving me any error in the file. Double check it.